# Why content of sendMessage is saved and how to disable it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I send a message from a ContextMenu within content.js to background.js. When I send a message, I expect to see an alert of just two variables which are sent with the request. When I send multiple request(few times in a row) I receive alerts including previously sent messages. It seems that all messages are stored somewhere. How do you disable this? I would like to see alerts of only the most recent message.

contents.js:

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var contents = window.getSelection().toString();
    switch (event.which) {
        case 3:
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({contents: contents, url: url}, function(response) {
                //console.log(response.farewell);
            });
            break;
    }
});
```

background.js

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.url) {
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function testFunc2(info, tab){
                alert(message.url);
                alert(typeof message.contents);

            }
        )
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "background.js"],
    //"page": "background.html",
    "persistent": true
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of this code

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (message.url) {
        chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function testFunc2(info, tab){
                alert(message.url);
                alert(typeof message.contents);

            }
        )
    }
});
```

What you are saying is that every onMessage event add a listener for onClicked events. So if you send three messages you end up with three testFunc2 methods acting on onClicked events.

Since you are trying to use information from two different asynchronous events. You will have to store one of them temporarily. Something like this would probably work.

```
var lastMessage;

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
     if (message.url) {
         lastMessage = message;
     } else {
         lastMessage = undefined;
     }
});
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if(lastMessage !== undefined) {
        testFunc2(message, info, tab);
    }
});

function testFunc2(info, tab){
    alert(message.url);
    alert(typeof message.contents);

    // cleanup
    lastMessage = undefined;    
});
```

Comment: I see. Let's say I put onClicked.addListener outside of onMessage.addListener. What I would like to achieve is: the user selects some html on any website(this information is caught by content.js), after that he clicks on contextMenu, and information about what he selected is sent to background.js. Any advice how to achieve this?

Comment: You'll have to store the results of one event and only trigger the final function if both events have happened. I added a code snippet that might work.